# How to convert my program of python and mysql into a exe file?

Tags: python, mysql

How do I convert my program of Python and my SQL into a executable file?
Please help with detailed information.

Comment: Check out [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: pyinstaller -F *.py

Answer (score 0):

Install pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

follow [These steps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)

Comment: I was using that link only. But if I connect it with mysql database,is there any other requirements? Pls help. I was able to execute my .py file but was not able to execute the program which is connected with database.

Comment: You can't. you would need to run the MySQL server yourself. Use sqlite or host your database on cloud like MongoDB and let the client connect to it remotely.