# How to convert my Python Project (GUI With Tkinter) into .exe where it having database dependence?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python gui project which having a database. i want to convert my project into .exe

How the end user will get database or how can convert my entire project along with database(mysql).

My requirement is end user want to have all the things along with db in a single .exe file.

Note: application is for windows and database will be located locally.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: you have to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63408345/15211592) link ...... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63408345/15211592

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But the link doesn't resolve my need..I need my exe file along with database..is it possible or Not ??

Comment: For local database, better use sqlite (just a file) instead of MySQL (required to run a server application).

Answer (score 0):

Use py2exe or pyinstaller.

> $ pip install pyinstaller

> $ pip install py2exe